# Server Sent Event with Play/scala on Heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, timeout, server-sent-events

I've used `Concurrent.broadcast` in a play app to create server sent event stream.
It works on my local machine but fails on heroku apparently due to timeout in the SSE connection:

```
heroku router - - at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/messagesFeed" host=xxxxxxxx request_id=0ef1f529-1336-409f-8e80-585ed3a47471 fwd="xxxxxxx" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=30163 status=503 bytes=963
```

Heroku doc says that they support SSE but also that their routers return an error 503 to the client if no data is sent every 55s. Does it means I have to sent heartbeats data ?